# change a number column to a calculated column in sharepoint list

Tags: list

I am trying to change the number column in my Sharepoint list to a calculated column. However, I am unable to find Calculated column while editing the list. How can I change a number column to a calculated column in sharepoint list?

Answer (score 0):

Am afraid you cannot change an existing number column to a calculated field as you would have loved. However, you can still achieve your intended goal by firing up your visual studio to created an Event Receiver.

In your ItemAdded event handler,
 1. Retrieve the values of the reference field for your calculation.
 2. Perform the calculation
 3. Update your existing number field with the result of the calculation.

Note: You can also do this using a simple workflow (either SPD or VS) and ensure your workflow is fired on Item Created. Then repeat the above steps in your workflow.